# Ajax Response add under each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a question that I can't seem to answer about Jquery Ajax Response.

I use a for each to select some data from `<p>` tags in each `info_div`. This data I then use to do a ajax call to a service that replies with a XML. I want to place some elements from this XML under each div from where I took the two variables. Each div should have it's own reply.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#action-button').click(function () {
        $(".info_div").each(function () {
            var var1 = $(this).find('p:nth-child(4)').text();
            var1 = var1.slice(-10);

            var var2 = $(this).find('p:nth-child(8)').text();
            var2 = var2.slice(-1);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.mypage.com/mypage&value1=" + "va1" + "&value2=" + "var2",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('member').each(function () {
                        var name = $(this).find("title").text()

                        /* how do I get this variable under each $('.info_div') from where I selected the var1 and var2
            Every attempt I made places all replies under all the divs in class .info_div */

                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I added a $(".info_div").filter(":contains("+var1+")").append(name); and I seem to have solved this :) I would really appreciate a more documented answer. Or a more elegant solution

Comment: if you paste the xml we will have a elegant solution

Comment: You can use Promises or Closures to deal with the async behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend you to send ajax requests in a loop. Better collect all your data, then send it to the server and handle the response.

Meanwhile, if you insist to do it in a loop, you should make a reference to the iterated element from `$(".indo_div)` collection, and use it in ajax callback.

```
$(".info_div").each(function() {
    var _that = $(this);
    var var1 =  $(this).find('p:nth-child(4)').text();
    var1 = var1.slice(-10);

    var var2 =  $(this).find('p:nth-child(8)').text();
    var2 = var2.slice(-1);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.mypage.com/mypage&value1=" + "va1" + "&value2=" + "var2",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('member').each(function(){
                var name = $(this).find("title").text()
                that.append(name);
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Your suggestion is working quite nice. I am still a beginner at this, a programmer by need not by choice :) I will look into how I can collect all the data and then do the server request all at once.